# opacity not working in ie9

Tags: html, css

I'm using opacity and I want to apply it on an image.

This is my CSS code:

```
img {
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}

img:hover {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    -khtml-opacity: 1.0; 
}
```

It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but it is not working in Internet Explorer 9. The problem is at the hover effect.

On the simple img the opacity works in IE9, but the hover effect doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Worked well for me. Did you try to put the DOCTYPE in?

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is not yet a CSS standard. However, it works in all modern browsers, and is a part of the W3C CSS 3 recommendation.

Please refer: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp

if no joy,

use compatibility mode

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Comment: Please **don't** refer to w3schools, ever. They're notoriously inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try this:
hit F12 (debugging console), then F5 (refresh). IE9 pops up a little box:
'Internet Explorer restricted this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls'
Click the button 'Allow Blocked content' and your opacity should work.

Not quite sure how to ensure that it works automatically.